# How to detect scattered frame in video

Tags: opencv, image-processing

In a video Due to low bandwidth some packet are destroying. because of that frame scatter is happening. i don't how to detect that.

I just want to detect scatter or ghost objects in the frame of video.How to detect this using python with opencv.

[image: Image link]

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. Can you add the tools you were using to achieve this in the title? Then it will be easier to find this on search engines. Can you add tags and a description of the image you added? You can also add what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Matheus This issue i have got in video basically what my understanding is due to low bandwidth some packet are destroying. because of that frame scatter is happening. i don't how to detect that.

Comment: IMO, this is barely possible. Because it takes a lot of image understanding to see that this image is "abnormal". You might think of detecting sudden changes from frame to frame, but legit sudden changes do occur in videos.